# Mockito mock object using real implementation

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Why is `mockMap` using the real implementation?
How do I prevent this?

In method testFirstKeyMatch

```
when(mockMap.keySet().toArray()[0])...
```

throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 when running the test.

**MaxSizeHashMap** is a LinkedHashMap with max size of 7,
throws an IndexOutOfBoundsException when I attempt to put more into.

**Profile** keeps track of something not essential for this.

SuperClass.java

```
public class SuperClass {

protected String[] days;
protected MaxSizeHashMap<String, String> map;

public SuperClass() {
    days = new String[7];
    map = new MaxSizeHashMap<String, String>();
    //...
}

void updateDays() {

    cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i = i + 1) {

        //adds short names "Mon", "Tue", ... to days
        days[i] = cal.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 
                Calendar.SHORT, Locale.US);

        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }
}

void firstKeyMatch(Profile profile) {

    updateDays(); 

    //checks if first key of map is not same as days[0]
    if (days[0] != map.keySet().toArray()[0]) {

        profile.add();

        //...
     }
 }
 }
```

SuperClassTest.java

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SuperClassTest {

@InjectMocks
private SuperClass spr = new SuperClass();

@Mock
private MaxSizeHashMap<String, String> mockMap;

@Mock
private Profile mockProfile;

//...

@Test
public void testFirstKeyMatch() {   

    when(mockMap.keySet().toArray()[0]).thenReturn(spr.days[0]);

    verify(mockProfile, never()).add();

}
}
```

Comment: Try this `when(mockMap.keySet()).thenReturn(new HashSet(Arrays.asList("your day string")));` by replacing "your day string" with whatever value you are testing with

Comment: It's not the real implementation, mocks return default values. In the case of `keySet()`, it's an empty collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://javadoc.io/page/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#2), mockito's implicit behaviour for a mock is to return [default values](http://javadoc.io/page/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEFAULTS).

> By default, for all methods that return a value, a mock will return either null, a primitive/primitive wrapper value, or an empty collection, as appropriate. For example 0 for an int/Integer and false for a boolean/Boolean.

In consequence, your `mockMap.keySet()` will return an empty hash-set, which you then convert to an empty array and try to retrieve the (non-existent) first element, hence the IOOBE.

[image: debugger]

In conclusion, mockito is not using the real implementation, but it's behaving normally as it's supposed to.

You did not post the entire constructor of `SuperClass`, but probably after you instantiate the map, you also populate it with values. If that's true, then one can argue that the exception is actually proof that mockito does not use the real implementation, because you'd really be getting the first element.

As for the solutions, well it's already been suggested to return your own hash set with whatever data you require (credits go to  Abubakkar):

```
when(mockMap.keySet()).thenReturn(new HashSet(Arrays.asList("your day string")));
```

Answer (score 1):

To redirect all `mockMap.keySet().toArray()[i]` calls to `spr.days[i]`, you can tell `mockMap` to return the `days` array when someone requests the key set.

```
Set keySetMock = mock(Set.class);
when(keySetMock.toArray()).thenReturn(spr.days);
when(mockMap.keySet()).thenReturn(keySetMock);
```